# Java installation in EC2

Tags: java, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, hadoop2

I'm in the process of setting up a hadoop cluster for learning purpose. For which I tried to install java and before installing i checked for the prior installation of java by running java -version command and got the below message

The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
* default-jre
* gcj-5-jre-headless
* openjdk-8-jre-headless
* gcj-4.8-jre-headless
* gcj-4.9-jre-headless
* openjdk-9-jre-headless
Try: sudo apt install

As per the advise in one of the threads I ran sudo apt-get update and got the below messages repeatedly

$sudo apt-get update
0% [Connecting to ap-south-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com (54.168.13.207)]

Err:1 http://ap-south-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Could not connect to ap-south-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (54.248.192.197), connection timed out [IP: 54.248.192.197 80]

Err:2 http://ap-south-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
  Unable to connect to ap-south-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 54.248.192.197 80]

Err:3 http://ap-south-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
  Unable to connect to ap-south-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 54.248.192.197 80]

Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1562::19 80]

Reading package lists... Done

W: Failed to fetch http://ap-south-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Could not connect to ap-south-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (54.248.192.197), connection timed out [IP: 54.248.192.197 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ap-south-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease  Unable to connect to ap-south-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 54.248.192.197 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ap-south-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/InRelease  Unable to connect to ap-south-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 54.248.192.197 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1562::19 80]

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

What should i do now ?

Will i face a similar problem while installin hadoop too ?

Thanks

Comment: can you show ur instance security grp settings?

Comment: @AmitKhandelwal Security Group: sg-113f2e7

Type    Protocol  Port Range  Destination Description
HTTP    TCP        80         0.0.0.0/0   for TCP HTTP
All traffic All    All        0.0.0.0/0
HTTPS  TCP    443       0.0.0.0/0   for TCP HTTPS

*************** the above table is crumbled to lines.

below is the explanation. 
for HTTP allocated port 80 and destination as 0.0.0.0/0
for HTTPS allocated port 443 and destination as 0.0.0.0/0

above all there is read-only entry by amazon for fail-safe

Comment: is your instance is launched in private subnet ? can you ping the ip of ubuntu of site from very you are trying to download.

Comment: @AmitKhandelwal - Sorry, I'm new to networking, I just went by the steps in a document for setting up hadoop cluster.  there is no mention about it. Where should i check for private subnet ?

Comment: is your instance is behind any firewall ? and are you using your company aws account or your private aws account ?

Comment: I'm using private aws account for learning.  how to determine whether an instance is behind a firewall?

Comment: did you create any VPC or subnet or using the default which is provided by aws?

Comment: I haven't created neither a VPC nor a subnet hence, should be using the default settings

Comment: yes, please use default setting .

Comment: i mean i find only the default settings, nothing else

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162479/discussion-between-amit-khandelwal-and-luckyluke).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the outbound internet access from your EC2 instance is blocked by something. It can be the security group/ACL/the VPN Settings.

Try pinging to some internet address and see if its working. Once that is resolved, it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the eye-opener. Have checked and update the outbound traffic table, still it's not working.  is there anything i need to do ?

Comment: Can you share the output of the ping command. You can use `ping www.google.com` and share the response from the specific EC2 instance

Comment: it hangs, no response and i need to close the SSH client

Comment: That is quite strange. Can you share more details like 1) What instance type you are using. 2) Is it having any Elastic IP/Public IP/ Public DNS? (You can see this in the "Description" section after selecting the EC2 Instance via AWS Management Console)

Comment: 1) Instance type is Ubuntu 64 bit on EC2. Trying to setup a hadoop cluster for learning.  ** 2) Yes it has IPv4 Public IP and Public DNS(IPv4). Should i create a Elastic IP ? **

Comment: Elastic IP is not required since its having a Public IP. What is the Instance Type? Is it t2.micro or something else? Also, check if you are able to ping your own Private IP using command `ping <your-private-ip>`

Comment: Yes, the instance type is t2.micro.  I'm able to ping the private ip.

Comment: That means, problem is with outbound access from your EC2 server to the internet. We need to check the ACL then. Navigate to VPC>Subnet> Select the subnet to which your EC2 instance belongs to. Then see the outbound rules. It should have 2 rules. `RULE1 : 100 | ALL Traffic | ALL | ALL | 0.0.0.0/0 | ALLOW
RULE2 : *   | ALL Traffic | ALL | ALL | 0.0.0.0/0 | DENY`

Comment: The subnet setting reflect the above by default (I havent changed anything) but still the issue is there